# Creating a Pie chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to create pie chart using row values. My problem here is I have data in 4 seperate cells. When i run the code below It takes only one cell value and ignores other values. It takes the value of G16 but not the values of H16, I16, J16, K16.

```
Sub Chart()
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G16:K16"),PlotBy:= _
    xlColumns
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
ActiveChart.HasTitle = False
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change plotBy value :

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G16:K16"),PlotBy:= _
xlRows
```

Comment: you have to deal with properties of charobject, in which your chart is embedded. So you just have to access activeChart's parent in your case  :             `With ActiveChart.Parent  
             .Top = 100  
             .Left = 100  
         End With`

Answer (score 0):

Take out the:

```
,PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Testing at my end seems to fix the issue.